# How to zoom/magnify on linux without compiz (bspwm)

Tags: linux, compiz, compton, accessibility, bspwm

I'd like to have the functionality described in [this video](https://youtu.be/sACNU_819TU?t=2m40s). Basically, use super+scrollup/down or pinch in/out on my touchpad to zoom in a certain area of the screen like on a phone or tablet.

Sadly I need compiz to get the described effect. How can I zoom in without using compiz?

I'm using Arch Linux with bspwm + compton.

What I've tried:

- `xzoom`, which can zoom but spawns a new window instead of zooming in on the spot. Not what I want.
- KDE's `kmag`, pretty much the same as `xzoom` but with a nice GUI.
- [Magnifier](https://github.com/minos-org/magnifier), where you can mouse over an area to zoom that area of the screen, which is not really what I want. I want to actually zoom in the whole screen like in the video above.

There's are open issues in compton's repositories:

- https://github.com/chjj/compton/issues/188 (dead repo)
- https://github.com/yshui/compton/issues/43 (new fork)

Comment: This is ancient. I wonder if you could make it work. [Virtual Magnifying Glass](http://magnifier.sourceforge.net/). Does the gnome [accessibility](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/a11y-mag.html.en) help?

Comment: Also, this github page [mangifier](https://github.com/minos-org/magnifier) seems to be a newer version of the sourceforge one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried the software you linked but it doesn't zoom in the whole screen, just a box, which is not what I want. How can I use gnome's accessibility in bspwm?

Comment: Ah, I thought you said "to zoom in a certain area of the screen". I am not sure how to use the gnome in bspwm, specifically.

Comment: @number9 Yeah I didn't really know how to describe it. The video shows it pretty well.

Comment: @number9 That magnifier is intriguing but also puzzling: why are all the files 8 years old? Why only LTS releases for Ubuntu?  Why does the github version *not* provide the source code it used to produce its binaries?

Answer (score 1):

For a similar zoom as compiz offers, you can resort to xfwm4 (xfce). It does full desktop zoom out of the box by using Alt + mousewheel.

Comment: The question was about how to achieve it without switching window manager.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any other way than these two.

You can either have a window, that contains the magnified part like `xzoom` and similar tools (some may use windows without border, what may look more like what you want) or a window manager that support zooming. I do not see another way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I run Xubuntu 18.04 and I've just learned that it comes with this feature out of the box!
So that you just click ALT + mouseWheel  to zoom in or out the Desktop.

Caution:  It's necessary to have enabled the window manager compositor (see print attached), which, by the way, I had disabled years ago by the time of system installation and only now that I was searching for it, I discovered that this awesome feature was already there!

*XFCE Menu >>> Settings >>> Window Manager Tweaks >>> Compositor tab >>> check enable display compositing*
[image: Compositor tweaks: check enable display compositing]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm looking for something that works on any window manager. This is just a feature in XFCE's window manager.